# How do I make a new df with selected rows based on a condition in r?

Tags: r, select, rows

I have a df with many sessions which will result in a converion. I want to make a new df with all rows that contain a conversion.

My df looks like:

```
 Sessionid       Clientid        Conversion_type
    1                1                 No_conv
    2                1                 No_conv
    3                1                 Online
    4                2                 No_conv
    5                2                 Offline
```

I want a new df that looks like:

```
Session Id       Clientid        Conversion_type
    3                1                  Online
    5                2                  Offline
```

There is also a date column, so I thought if I order on Client_id, than it automatically orders on date for those id's. Then, I could select the rows that contain the tail value of the Clientid's. However, this is not working.

I hope somewone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use comparison operator to get the subset of rows where the 'Conversion_type' is not equal to 'No_conv'

```
df2 <- subset(df1, Conversion_type != 'No_conv')
df2
#     Sessionid Clientid Conversion_type
#3         3        1          Online
#5         5        2         Offline
```

Or if it is based on the position, i.e. need the last row per 'Clientid', use `duplicated` to create a logical vector in `subset` to subset the rows

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(Clientid, fromLast = TRUE))
# Sessionid Clientid Conversion_type
#3         3        1          Online
#5         5        2         Offline
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we can group by 'Clientid' and `slice` the last row (`n()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Clientid) %>%
  slice(n())
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sessionid = 1:5, Clientid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), Conversion_type = c("No_conv", "No_conv", "Online", "No_conv", 
"Offline")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```